# Matplot and Pandas pivot table define colors based on multiple indexes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

In python 3 using pandas and matplotlib, I have a simple data set with 2 indexes (Cat and Role)

```
Cat,Role,W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,W6,W7
mgt,CP,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
mgt,sm,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
tech,arch,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
tech,dev,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
tech,lead,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
tech,dev2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart where the color is based on the category and hue based on role.
up to now all I managed to get is a color based on both indexes, using this code:

```
ax = df.plot.bar( subplots=False,stacked=True,cmap=plt.get_cmap('Dark2'),edgecolor='Black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

what I would like to get
[image]

Comment: *the color is based on the category and hue based on role* I'm not following this. Can you add a sketch of what you are expecting?

Comment: here the 2 rows from tech category are from different base color ( green and grey) and mgt cateory is also in green. I would like both tech rows to be different shades of green (or any over color) and mgt category to be from a different color.

Comment: I have added more data to better illustrate the color changes and a sketch of the target.